# How can I insert and update based on results query

Tags: sql, oracle, select, plsql, insert

I need to make a query to insert and update based on select results. Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table1(name) 
SELECT 'myname' FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.lastname = 'lastname';
```

That query is supposed to return multiple rows so then I need to update age field from table2 based on that results and that's I don't know how to aprroach it. Any idea?

Comment: Please be more clear what you want to do: What has an update of the age column of table2 to do with an insert in table1? I think you should provide sample input of both tables and the expected outcome for both tables after your commands have been executed.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the oracle merge statment. Since you have not elaborated your question, giving the exact answer is not possible.